# Facebook App for Arbitrary HTML?

Tags: webapp-rec, facebook, html

I'd like to find an application on facebook which would allow me to add a tab to my page that contains simple HTML - like a list of items, or a couple paragraphs, etc. Is there a good solution anybody else has found success with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Static FBML **(defunct)** `http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=4949752878` application allows you to add a tab on your Facebook Page (not your personal profile) containing static FBML.  [FBML](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/) (Facebook Markup Language) is Facebook's own variant of HTML.  Many common HTML tags will work, if you do not use Javascript.  There are also some Facebook-specific tags, which help to make up for the lack of Javascript and allow for better integration with Facebook.

Comment: This application is no longer available on Facebook.  FBML has been deprecated for developers as well.